Avoid conversion of bytes to str in clickhouse-connect
I want to read bytes from ClickHouse using clickhouse-connect driver. I don't provide any encodings when I send a query. Under the hood it tries to decode these bytes to string using utf8 encoding, then fails and converts to hex string. Then I convert this hex str to bytes by manually calling bytes.fromhex(x). How to avoid all of these conversions? Can I just receive bytes object?

Did you try setting a read_format for your query or the specific column you are reading?  https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/integrations/python#read-formats
